# From C# code to DAG (Program Graph) for Catch Exception and Catch IOException

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, ioexception

I use the following partial code, where I the relevant line are enumerated by `#number`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace PS_5
{ 
    Class BinarySearch
    {
        Static void Main (string[] args)
        {
#2      int[] elemArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        .....

#15     StreamWriter sw = null;
            try 
            {
#16             sw = new StreamWriter ("output.txt")
#17.1, 17.2, 17.3               for (int i=0; i<elemArray.Length; i++)
                {
#18                 sw.Write(elemArray[i] + ",");
                }
#19         sw.WriteLine();
            }
#21         catch (IOException ex)
            {
#22             Console.WriteLine (ex.Message)
            }
#23         catch (Exception ex)
            {
#24             Console.WriteLine (ex.Message)
            }
        finally
        {
#25         sw.Flush();
#26         sw.Close();
        }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to transfer this code into DAG (Program Graph).
I would like to ask the following:

(1) Is there a dependency between line 17.3 (`i++`) to line 23 (`catch (Exception ex)` )? is there a way that line 23 will be executed after line 17.3?
As far as I see, line 23 is aimed to catch an error for `i` which is an integer. In case of exceeding its maximal number there won't be an error since `i` will get its minimum value. So is there another situation that line 23 will be executed after line 17.3?

(2) I know that there is a dependency between line 18 to line 21 since in line 18 we use the `Write` command that is an IO and there might be an exception in IO. However the content of the `Write` command includes also `elemArray[i]`. Is there a chance that line 23 the regular `catch Exception` will run because of it?

(3) Is there any dependency between lines 21 and 23. Are they mutual exclusive? I mean if `catch IOException` works than the `Catch Exception` won't work and vise versa? Do they share the same stack for the executing the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

Q1. Technically, yes: you may have an *integer overflow*:

```
 int i = int.MaxValue;

 checked {
   i++; // <- integer overflow
 }
```

however, it's *very unlike case*.

Q2. Yes, technically, you can have *out of range* exception: if  `elemArray.Length == int.MaxValue` then condition `i<elemArray.Length` is *always true* and

```
 int i = int.MaxValue;

 unchecked {
   i++; // <- no integer overflow (thanks to "uncheked"), i is negative now

   var x = elemArray[i]; // <- Out of range (since i is negative)
 }
```

it's a *very unlike case* as well as the 1st one.

Q3. Yes, they are mutually exclusive either `catch (IOException ex)` is called either `catch (Exception ex)` or none of them.

A tip: you may find *Linq* being a better solution instead of that stuff with readers, streams:

```
  File.WriteAllText("output.txt", String.Join(",", lemArray));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Dmitry Bychenko, I would like to ask if in the regular case without using check and unchecked there is still a chance for Q1 and Q2?

Comment: You use `checked` or `unchecked` (should the system check for integer overflow) either *explictly* (`checked`, `uncheked`) or *implictly* - `Settings/Build/Advanced Build Settings "Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow"`. The *default* behaviour (VS 2013) is `uncheked`